# Install Pulsar-manager on kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-pulsar

I want to use pulsar-manager for GUI management, monitoring tool and following this https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-pulsar-manager/. In this on step ( Set administrator account and password ) , when I ran ->

```
  curl -H 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: $CSRF_TOKEN' -H 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=$CSRF_TOKEN;' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/users/superuser -d '{"name": "admin", "password": "apachepulsar", "description": "test", "email": "username@test.org"}'**
```

This cmd it throws error with below

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: $CSRF_TOKEN'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: XSRF-TOKEN=$CSRF_TOKEN;'
{"timestamp":"2021-10-12T03:27:07.419+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/pulsar-manager/users/superuser"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: admin,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: apachepulsar,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: email`
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 18
```

After fixing the above command, I use

`curl -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN:aki79b0c-5f32-49b9-94a4-26cd4e93da92" -H "Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=aki79b0c-5f32-49b9-94a4-26cd4e93da92" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/users/superuser -d "{"name": "admin", "password": "apachepulsar", "description": "test", "email": "pgandhap@in.ibm.com"}"`

Now, I am not able to login to pulsar-manager ui using the above credentials . It says incorrect username and password

Comment: Typo. The single quotes should be double quotes so the bash variables get loaded correctly

Comment: Thanks it worked . now i am able to set the username and password using the command below curl -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN:aki79b0c-5f32-49b9-94a4-26cd4e93da92" -H "Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=aki79b0c-5f32-49b9-94a4-26cd4e93da92" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/users/superuser -d "{"name": "admin", "password": "apachepulsar", "description": "test", "email": "pgandhap@in.ibm.com"}"
After that i am not able to login to pulsar-manager ui using the above credentials . It says incorrect username and password . please help on the same .

Comment: I've never used this tool. Please edit your question to include the new code or error messages you get

Comment: I didn't get any error message after ran the above command . But while logging with these credentials in ui , at that time it throws error with incorrect username or password .

Comment: I think your problem is still with quotes. See `-d "{"name"...}"`... The outermost quotes should be single quotes since you're sending a literal. Or you can use postman, for example, rather than curl

Comment: As per your suggestion , Iam using postman to set account and password . After hitting the url in postman , i got this response -> " message " : " Please login " .

Then i tried to login with the same credentials . which says incorrect username or password

Comment: And i tried by replacing double quotes with single quotes in the command with below 

C:\Users\Pavankalyan>curl -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: $CSRF_TOKEN" -H "Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=$CSRF_TOKEN;" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/users/superuser -d '{"name": "admin", "password": "apachepulsar", "description": "test", "email": "username@test.org"}'

Comment: I got below error :

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: admin,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: apachepulsar,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: email
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 18

Comment: You're getting shell errors, so your quoting is still wrong, and so I suggest not using curl anymore... Other than that, I have personally never used pulsar, so I cannot give anymore suggestions other than reach out to their Slack, Github issues, or mailing lists - https://pulsar.apache.org/en/contact/